# Mostrar Input al cambiar valor Select

Tags: javascript, php

no logro ocultar / mostrar un INPUT en función del valor de un SELECT, tengo un select que armo de la siguiente forma:

```
    <select name="fname[]<?php echo $i; ?>" id="selector<?php= $rol['id']; ?>" class="ejemplo3">
                
                    <?php
                $centro="";
$re=$SQLConn->query("SELECT * FROM centros where centrocoste = '0' or (centrocoste >= '2' and centrocoste <= '109') order by centrocoste ASC");

while($col=$re->fetch_array())  {                          
            ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $col[2]; ?>" <?php if ($centro== $col[2]) {?> selected="selected" <?php }?>><?php echo $col[2]; ?></option>                
                <?php 
                }               
                ?>
</select>
```

pretendo que simplemente al cambiar de valor ( es para que no se olviden de realizar la selección), aparezca es siguiente INPUT

```
<td><input type="text" name="lname<?php echo $i; ?>" placeholder="Código 5 dígitos"  pattern="(([0-9]{5}))" required/></td>
```

lo he intentado con lo siguiente pero no me funciona, imagino que tengo el problema con el nombre y el id del select.

```
 var fname = document.getElementById('fname[]');

fname.addEventListener('change',function(){
if(this.value == '0'){
document.getElementById('ldest').style.display = 'none';
}else{
document.getElementById('ldest').style.display = 'block';
}
});
```

Código del select e INPUT

```
     <table width="50%" align="center" border="0">
                
                <tr>
                  
                    <th>Tienda/s</th>                   
                </tr>               
            <?php               
                for($h=1; $h<=$_POST["no_of_ted"]; $h++)   //for($i=1; $i<=$num; $i++)     //for($i=1; $i<=$_POST["no_of_rec"]; $i++)
                {               
            ?>
                <td>
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <select name="fname[]<?php echo $i; ?>" id="selector<?php= $rol['id']; ?>" onchange="funcion(this);">               
            <?php
                $centro="";
                $re=$SQLConn->query("SELECT * FROM centros where centrocoste = '0' or (centrocoste >= '2' and centrocoste <= '109') order by centrocoste ASC");
                while($col=$re->fetch_array())  {                          
            ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $col[2]; ?>" <?php if ($centro== $col[2]) {?> selected="selected" <?php }?>><?php echo $col[2]; ?></option>                
           <?php 
                }
               
            ?>
</select>   
</td>   
           <?php
                }
           ?>               
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="9"><a >Artículos Pedidos</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>##</th>
                    <th>Fecha</th>
                    <th>Articulo</th>
                    <th>Referencia</th>  
                    <th>Descripción</th>
                    <th>Observaciones</th>

                    
                </tr>
            <?php
                $desc = "ROTACIONES CENTRAL";
                $fecha=date('d-m-Y');
                for($i=1; $i<=$_POST["no_of_rec"]; $i++)   
                {
             ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
                        <td ><input  value="<?php echo $fecha; ?>" readonly/></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="lname<?php echo $i; ?>" placeholder="Código 5 dígitos"  pattern="(([0-9]{5}))" required/></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="lref<?php echo $i; ?>" placeholder="Referencia" pattern="(([0-9]{5-10}))" required/></td>
                        <td><input  value="<?php echo $desc; ?>"  readonly/></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="lobs<?php echo $i; ?>" placeholder="Observaciones" /></td>
                        
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="9" align="center">

                        <button type="submit" name="save_mul">Aceptar</button>

                        <a href="index.php" >Pagina Principal</a>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿El _select_ está también en la tabla y en la misma fila del _input_?

Comment: Buenas, gracias, está en la misma tabla pero en distinta fila, añado en la pregunta  para que se vea mejor

Comment: Tienes dos ciclos diferentes, uno para x cantidad de _select_, basados en `$_POST["no_of_ted"]` (por cierto, el índice es `$h`, pero internamente usas `$i`); y otro para x cantidad de _input_, basados en `$_POST["no_of_rec"]`, ¿cómo estableces la relación entre uno y otro?

Comment: Eso viene desde otro hoja anterior, donde se marca en 2 INPUT el número de SELECT que van a aparecer y el número de filas de INPUTs que vamos a tener, igual es más sencillo ocultar el botón "submit" mientras no exista un cambio en el/ los SELECTS ?

Comment: Efectivamente, es mucho más sencillo lo del botón, porque no hay relación aparente entre _selects_ e _inputs_.

Comment: y en qué debería de modificar mi código inicial de INPUT, porque no acabo de verlo, gracias